# How can web search be disabled in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Build 1607)?

Tags: cortana, windows-10-v1607

In the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (build 1607) it is no longer possible to disable cortana, only decline to sign in. Cortana has completely replaced the previously available Windows Search feature that could be enabled by disabling Cortana. How can one therefore disable the web search aspect of Cortana, and return local results only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To [disable Cortana](http://winaero.com/blog/disable-cortana-in-windows-10-anniversary-update-version-1607/), start regedit.exe, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`, create a new `32-bit DWORD` value here named `AllowCortana` and leave its value data as 0.

[image]

After a reboot you see the Cortana Logo is gone and the local search opens:

[image]

if this also doesn't disable web search, set the value `BingSearchEnabled` to `0` under `HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search]
"AllowCortana"=dword:00000000
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Does it actually work though? Some group policy features have been disabled in this update...

Comment: @AndréBorie yes, see the picture ;)

Comment: And can you, too, confirm that this is the situation for the Anniversary Update 1607 and not an earlier build like 1511? The update has changed a lot.

Comment: @seagull, yes, this is version 1607, see the updated picture ;)

Comment: Although this answer requires completely disabling cortana, I've not seen another way to disable web search so I'm going to accept this answer. I've verified it works in Windows 10 Pro Build 1607.

Comment: @EarlSven try to set the value **BingSearchEnabled** to 0 under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search** and set **AllowCortana** to 1. Is this what you want?

Comment: +1 I had to create `Windows Search` though since this key didn't exist before.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot if you restart explorer.exe instead. I tested this.

Comment: @Anon234_4521 yes, but not all systray icons get restored after killing explorer.exe so this is not the best solution

Comment: To do this in one command.  `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" /f /v AllowCortana /t REG_SZ /d 0`

Comment: This registry key does not exist, I'm using Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1107461/57662) is wrong: it disables Cortana but does nothing to prevent web searches.

According to http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-web-search-in-windows-10 you need to do the following:

1. Run "gpedit.msc"
2. Navigate to "Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Search"
3. Double click "Do not allow web search"
4. Select "Enabled", click "OK".
5. Repeat step 4 for "Don't search the web or display web results in Search"

I've personally tested this and it worked for me.

**NOTE**: This will only work on Windows 10 Pro edition. Home edition does not support "gpedit.msc".

Comment: Anybody using Home edition cannot follow your advice because gpedit.msc is not available to them. The accepted answer worked perfectly for me with Windows 10 Home as well.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is actually in the related bar.
Open Cortana, click the settings cog and turn off the "Search online and include web results" option

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm 100% that your image is from Windows 10 Anniversary Update, build 1607, and not a prior build, as I do not believe this menu exists in the latest version, which is what OP question is about.

Comment: @seagull I can confirm it does indeed exist

Comment: @Ramhound I don't seem to see that option on 1607. Tested on both Pro and Enterprise.

Comment: I've just been verifying these answers on Windows 10 Pro and this screenshot appears to be from Build 1511, and matches the method I've previously been employing. This method does not appear to apply to build 1607.

Comment: I can confirm what Lister said. I have two Windows 10 in hand, one with this option, one without. I'm not sure if the version does count, however I have the option available in "version 1607 (build 14393.321)", while there is not in "version 1607 (build 14393.187)".

Comment: -1 this does not exist in the Anniversary Update which is what OP explicitly asked for and what I need.

Comment: These settings have now changed.